# can javascript event bubbling be done on html controls

Tags: javascript

Can I have a separate `js` file which performs action on html control events like

I have three tables on a webpage whenever I put over mouse on any table a alert should show.

I want the code in a separate js file and I cannot use id or class as selector 
the selector should be the html control only like table.onmouseOver

I have tried using the

```
table.onmouseover = handler;
function handler(event){
  alert("mouseOver done");
  return false;
}
```

but it is not working

```
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr id="red">
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jill</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td>50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>94</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>80</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </br>
    </br>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>b</th>
            <th>c</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>33</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>111</td>
            <td>222</td>
            <td>333</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
   </body>
```

As listed above I want to fire event whenever a mouse comes over any of the one table without id or class selector

Comment: It looks like you just need a way to get a reference to your table objects.  Check out [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below Code Snippet

```js
function handler(event){
  alert("mouseOver done");
  return false;
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { 
var oTables = document.getElementsByTagName("table");

for(var i=0;i<oTables.length;i++)
{
  oTables[i].addEventListener("mouseover",handler);
}


});
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr id="red">
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jill</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td>50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>94</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>80</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>b</th>
            <th>c</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>33</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>111</td>
            <td>222</td>
            <td>333</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
   </body>
   </html>
```